# promise access value outside of the 'then' function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, resolve

Would like to call configuration function defined at file B.js from File A.ts and set the return  object in a  config variable.

However I could not access the correct value for the config var or var x which are both reside outside of the 'then' function.

i could get the correct value inside the 'then' function, but not outside the 'then' function.

Code in A.tx

```
import {configuration} from "../../B";
var x = configuration("typeA").then(function(data){
        console.log("inside then fct: "+ JSON.stringify(data));
        config=data;
        return (data);
})
console.log("config"+JSON.stringify(config));
console.log("outside then fct: "+ JSON.stringify(x));
```

Code in B.js

```
exports.configuration = function (type) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var url = '/api/code/configuration/' + type;

    c.makeRequest('get', url)
    .then(function (data) {
       console.log("confi: "+JSON.stringify(data));
       resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       reject(error);
    });
 });
};
```

Comment: Either put all the logic that depends on the asynchronous info inside the `.then` or `await` the Promise, there's not really any other decent way

Comment: i have tried various solution like resolve(data) but could not get the result outside of the then function

Comment: tried your suggestion, var x = await configuration("typeA").then(function(data){
     
        return (data);
}) finally works for the code after that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!